# How Can I increase or decrease a number in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, insert

I want to increase data in MongoDB whenever I insert new data. I am using MongoDB and express

Comment: for what purpose? a unique id? to keep an overall document count?

Comment: In case you are updating a document, you use the `$inc` update operator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.